# Set Vim bracket highlighting colors

Tags: vim

I'm using *:set showmatch* to highlight the matching bracket or brace when the cursor is over one.

I'd like to change the highlight-color so that it's radically different from the cursor color, because I've got the situation shown in the screenshots.

When the cursor is over the second brace:

[image: Cursor over the second brace]

And when the cursor is to the immediate-right of the brace:

[image: Cursor to the right]

This uses my terminal color scheme, which is taken from [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized). Unfortunately, it's a bit of a pain to see which highlight is the brace matching and which is the cursor, when the braces are close together.

Is there a Vim setting I can use to change the color of that to, say, the *bold magenta* ANSI? I'm not particularly interested in remapping my ANSI colors within the terminal or shell - I'd like a Vim-specific option, if it exists.

Comment: Yeah, this is kind of nuts. In Neovim, using the built-in colorschemes and [lsp-zero](https://github.com/VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim), the matching highlight is identical to the cursor, and the cursor disappears briefly when you pass over a match, so it looks like the cursor just jumped to the matching bracket. Not sure yet exactly which piece of config is at fault, but It's maddening.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can change the colors to, e.g., blue over green:

```
hi MatchParen cterm=none ctermbg=green ctermfg=blue
```

Just put it in your *[.vimrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)#Vim_script)* file.

Basically, `cterm` determines the style, which can be `none`, `underline` or `bold`, while `ctermbg` and `ctermfg` are, as their names suggest, background and foreground colors, so change them as you see fit.

For your case, you may want

```
hi MatchParen cterm=bold ctermbg=none ctermfg=magenta
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  If you use the GUI version, this works pretty well.      "hi MatchParen  guibg=NONE guifg=blue gui=bold"

Comment: Came across this answer while I was looking how to turn that feature (MatchParen) off, because I found the colors so irritating (molokai). Someone should fix the default...

Comment: thnx! I'm using Neovim and in my case I had to set `hi MatchParen guifg=lightblue guibg=darkblue`.

Comment: Anyone have a Lua (Neovim) version of this?

Answer (score 8):

I'm using the `vividchalk` color scheme with `macvim`, and none of the various solutions I tried worked for me.  But I searched the file:

```
~/.vim/colors/vividchalk.vim
```

for `MatchParen` and I found this line:

```
call s:hibg("MatchParen","#1100AA","DarkBlue",18)
```

I commented out that line, then I copied that line, and I changed it to:

```
 call s:hibg("MatchParen","#FF0000","Red",18)
```

which succeeded in highlighting the matching parenthesis in red, which is a LOT easier to see.   I hope that helps someone else.

If you want to briefly jump to the opening bracket/paren/brace when you type the closing bracket/paren/brace, then adding:

```
set showmatch
```

to ~/.vimrc worked for me.

**A very handy trick** is setting the cursor on a bracket/paren/brace and then typing `%` to jump to the matching bracket/paren/brace.  That is especially useful when the matching bracket/paren/brace has scrolled off the page.  Typing `%` a second time will jump back to where you came from.

Answer (score 6):

The colours that I use for Vim highlighting (from my *~/.vimrc* file):

```
" set sensible highlight matches that don't obscure the text
:highlight MatchParen cterm=underline ctermbg=black ctermfg=NONE
:highlight MatchParen gui=underline guibg=black guifg=NONE
```

*NONE* uses the character colour from the
`:colourscheme ron` (or whichever you prefer from `:!ls $VIMRUNTIME/colors`).

Answer (score 5):

Try `:!ls $VIMRUNTIME/colors`. These are default color schemes Vim supply.

Then change color scheme `:colorscheme name`, find the color scheme that *you* like and copy the color scheme: `:!cp $VIMRUNTIME/colors/<name>.vim ~/.vim/colors/new_name.vim`

Edit it and set with the color scheme command or better add `colorscheme name` to the *[.vimrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)#Vim_script)* file. After changes to color file`:colorscheme name`, reload Vim's colors.

It's handy to use `:vsp` in create a vertical split in Vim. Edit the colors file in one half, and check changes in other. I used [nye17's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746750/set-vim-bracket-highlighting-colors/10746829#10746829) and added the `hi MatchParen` line to my color_file.vim. It works just fine.

Links:

- [Vim help](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:highlight)
- [How to control colors](http://alvinalexander.com/linux/vi-vim-editor-color-scheme-syntax)
- [About terminal colors](https://codeyarns.com/2015/03/18/how-to-check-colors-supported-by-terminal)

Comment: Peter Mortensen, thank you for your help.