# How to get matching brace highlighting without cursor jump in vim

Tags: vim, editor

I am running vim 7.3 on several machines. By default MatchParen is enabled on all of my instances. Using gvim on my windows machine, it is doing exactly what I want - when my cursor is on a bracket, paren, etc. it visually highlights the match. It does not affect cursor navigation. However, on my Ubuntu boxes, when I move the cursor onto the character, it actually jumps to the match.

I'm sure that the behavior is caused by MatchParens because if I do a :NoMatchParen, it stops. Unfortunately, I also don't get the highlighting at that point. I can't figure out where my settings differ, though.

I'll like you even more if you can point me towards a plugin that will always highlight the closest enclosing pair of characters around my current position (like a code oriented version of MatchTagsAlways)

Comment: The cursor isn't jumping. You probably have bad colors chosen.

Comment: Check :set matchtime? The cursor does jump to the next matching parens, but just for a few tenths of a second and then it should go back.

Comment: @FDinoff - I've seen others say that in response to similar questions, and it's (sometimes) demonstrably untrue. I have had situations where I entered insert mode after moving to an opening paren and had it appear after the closing paren. Of course, now that I'm trying to duplicate the behavior, I can't. matchtime=5 in both environments. You are correct that the color is bad, though, it makes it look like the matching thing is focused.

Comment: Well, that's the default value. Maybe it was just a bug. Or something else interfering. Starting vim with the -u NONE option is useful in these kind of situations.

Comment: @rhuffstedtler I have been wrong before. However, the default configuration shouldn't have that. If your configuration has it, it means that you put it in and you should know that you put that setting in. (If you didn't put it in how did it get there). Anyways, I would be interested in seeing what causes it if it actually is jumping.

Comment: @FDinoff - I was pretty sure I had just duplicated the scenario on a different machine, but it turns out it was bad colors there as well. I think reality has finally beaten my stubbornness into submission. If you'd like to turn your comment into an answer, I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: The [accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746750/set-vim-bracket-highlighting-colors) shows how to modify `.vimrc` such that the foreground and background colors of the matched character are altered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cursor isn't jumping. The color scheme probably has defined bad colors for the `MatchParen` highlight group which makes it look like the cursor is jumping.

Answer (score 5):

When `showmatch` is set, the cursor is actually jumping, and the following line fixes the problem:

```
set matchtime=0
```

More details:
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'matchtime'

Comment: I found this page because I was experiencing this cursor jump while editing inline javascript in an html file. This fixed my issue and I no longer have the second-long delay after every closing-brace. However, after reading other answers and doing some investigation, I found that removing `set showmatch` from my `.vimrc` had the same effect. So, +1 for an answer which works, but there are other options.

Answer (score 5):

Just like FDinoff said in the accepted answer, this is probably only a problem of colors.

So if the color of the matching "paren" disorients you, tweaking colors of background and foreground is likely the solution.

### But HOW do you do this?? ^^

I've had quite a journey through the [vimdoc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html) (it was not easy).
I've tested a whole bunch of variables and found that the relevant tweak is the `[hi]ghlight` [command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:highlight) and specifically the `MatchParen` group.

### The solution

Adding this in my .vimrc did the trick:

```
hi MatchParen ctermfg=208 ctermbg=bg
```

Note that vim config files are read from top to bottom, and some types of "words" are matched by several options. For example, a boolean could also be a keyword. Thus you have to pay attention to the order of these options.

### How does this work?

My problem was that the background had the flashy color while the foreground had the color of the background of my terminal, which made it really confusing. Thus switching colors was the solution *for me*. But maybe you will have to tweak it differently.

First, you can **check the current value for highlight MatchParen** by entering the following command (while inside vim, in normal mode):

```
:hi MatchParen
```

You'll see `hi MatchParen` followed by `XXX` in the current style, followed by a list of `argument=value` separated by spaces.

The important arguments are `ctermfg` and `ctermbg` for the "terminal" vim, `guifg` and `guibg` for the "gui" vim. (Where fg means foreground and bg means background)

You can **change a value and see the result in real time**. Just put your cursor over a match character and enter the following command:

```
:hi MatchParen SomeArgument=SomeValue
```

This will not be saved, so don't worry. When you find a proper combination of values, you can add them in your .vimrc as shown above.

Personally, I set `ctermfg` to `208` (orange color) and `ctermbg` to `bg` (a keyword for the current background color, if known by vim).
If you use vim in a gui, take a look [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#highlight-guibg) for the available choice of colors.

Answer (score 1):

Running default `gVim` (v7.4.461) without any configuration (i.e. no `.vim` files) in `openSUSE 13.2 Legacy 32 Bit`, `:set showmatch?` reveals that `showmatch` is on at start, which is not [Vim's stated default behaviour](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'noshowmatch'). We can account for this by adding `:set noshowmatch` in our `.vimrc`.