# vim - change bracket highlighting colors

Tags: vim, themes

I use [Mononoki](https://madmalik.github.io/mononoki/) in combination with [happy hacking](https://github.com/YorickPeterse/happy_hacking.vim) and the latter has an extremely subtle highlighting of matching parenthesis.

How do I change the colors used for highlighting matching brackets in a vim color scheme?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `MatchParen` in the color scheme's vim file (commonly found in `~/.vim/colors/`).

In the case of happy hacking, change:

```
call s:Color("MatchParen", "NONE", "NONE", "NONE", "NONE", "bold")
```

[image: happy hacking default]

to for example:

```
call s:Color("MatchParen", s:yellow, s:gray4, "NONE", "NONE", "bold")
```

[image: happy hacking edited]

I learned what to look for thanks to [Set vim bracket highlighting colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746750/set-vim-bracket-highlighting-colors).

Answer (score 1):

Use `ctermfg` to change the foreground color and `ctermbg` to change the background color of the `MatchParen` tag.

For example:

```
hi MatchParen ctermfg=black
hi MatchParen ctermbg=white
```